# Raspberry pi 3 putty connection error

Tags: ssh, putty, laptop

[image]

ı want to connect my raspberry to laptop via putty(ssh), but when i enter my password(raspberry) i am getting this error

Comment: Can you login with the previously mentioned username and password using a monitor and keyboard? Also to rule out the obvious are the caps lock on?

Comment: Are you running the Raspbian operating system, or something else?

Comment: Yes i try to run Raspian, but i solved problem. Ip scanner's error. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you've already changed this password to something different or you make mistake while providing password or you use wrong ip address.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had used wrong ip adress. Now it works :)